# How to fill a div with a class col-md-8 in bootstrap and jssor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jssor

I want that the images container in the jssor component fill the div with a class col-md-8. I tried  delete width and height, change the position attribute, doesn't work with percent nor auto attributes, most of the time the image disappear. Is there a way to do this??

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="slider1_container" class="" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 650px; height: 350px;">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div data-u="slides" class="" style="cursor: move; position: relative; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 650px; height: 350px;">
            @foreach (var image in Model.RandomAlbum.Images)
            {
                <div><img src="~/Content/uploads/original/@image.Name" data-u="image" class="img-responsive" /></div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just put the slider into the 'col-md-8' with no change. What's the problem them?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work, I have to specify a height and width, If I don't do that, the image doesn't show!!! I just want the image fill the div with class col-md-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jssor slider is specified with fixed size, but you can scale it to any size by calling api $ScaleWidth.

Use the following code, you can fit the slider in parent container.

```
    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
    //while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
        if (parentWidth) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-make-responsive-slider.html

Comment: the modified code you provided worked perfect for me thanks :D